# Save html page with Silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight, browser, xap

How can i save html page with silverlight object within?
I need to be able later to reopen page and to view sl content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is not dependent on the particular page you should be able to save the HTML and then separetely download the .xap file.  The place the .xap in the same folder as the html file and you should be able to view it locally in the browser.

This won't work if the Silverlight app is dependent on a service on the hosting web page (RIA or an explicit WCF service).